# How to convert local time to UTC time same date but time set to midnight

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this time

```
Tue Dec 05 2017 17:05:51 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

I want to convert this into

```
Tue Dec 05 2017 00:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: Convert string to date, change time, reconvert to string. If any of these steps blocks you (after you researched them), then ask again.

Comment: Alternatively you can use this plugin: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Very new to Moment.js . Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this->

```js
var date = new Date().toString();
var dateArray = date.split(' ');
dateArray.splice(4);
dateArray.push('00:00:00 GMT');
var newDate = dateArray.join(' ');
console.log(newDate);
```

Comment: You can, but it looks like a pain in the back. Why not using `Date.parse()` after removing that `(IST)`?

Comment: SInce the `Date.parse()` method returns numbers. and I think he wants a string containing time as `00:00:00`. 
ref-> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: With this, it seems like it's gonna be a pain using Date.getTime() to fetch the unix timestamp value. Any suggestions using Moment.js?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this:

```
//Convert string to Date object
var d = new Date(Date.parse('Tue Dec 05 2017 17:05:51 GMT+0530 (IST)'))
```

and then run:

```
//crux: get utc offset from epoch in milliseconds and use .toUTCString(...) to offset timezone
var ms = Date.UTC(d.getYear()+1900, d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), 0, 0, 0)
console.log(new Date(ms).toUTCString(ms))
```

Let me know if this does not suit your requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're asking for UTC I think this one is the easiest:

```js
var input = "Tue Dec 05 2017 17:05:51 GMT+0530 (IST)"
var date = new Date(input);
date.setHours(1);
date.setMinutes(0);
date.setSeconds(0);
date.setMilliseconds(0);
console.log(date.toUTCString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked best for us.  Keep in mind, this returns an ISO string which you may not need.

```
const formatDate = (dateValue) => {
  const date = new Date(dateValue)
  const minuteOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset()
  date.setMinutes(minuteOffset * -1)
  return date.toISOString()
}
```